# Comparing directivity patterns of an un-tapered and tapered uniform linear array

Tags: beamforming

Assume we have a uniform linear array (ULA) with N elements.  We wish to compare the performance of a tapered (let us presume Taylor 4-bar, -30dB side-lobe) array to an un-tapered array.  Let the taper vector be **w**.  Assume that the taper functions are normalized such that sum(**w**)=1.  With that constraint, the directivity of the array is calculated as 1/(**w**'* **w**) using Matlab notation for a transpose (') and a dot product (*).  The constraint that sum(**w**)=1 is known as the *distortionless* constraint.  For example, the directivity for an un-tapered array will be 10log(N), and that of the tapered array (T4b30) will be ~0.7 dB less than that, as one would expect.  The *beam patterns* calculated with the normalized weights, however, will both have a maximum of unity on the main response axis.  We wish to display the two beam patterns on the same plot, un-normalized.

Directivity is a power function (as opposed to voltage,) thus the use of 10log(D) to calculate the *Directivity index* in dB.  Beam patterns, however, are a voltage function, i.e., the power pattern is the square of the absolute value of the beam pattern.  Thus we calculate the beam patterns in dB as 20*log(B).

Now calculate the beam pattern *without* normalizing the weights, i.e., sum(**w**)=N.  The resulting beam patterns will each have a maximum of N, or 20log(N) in dB, which is twice the directivity index of the un-tapered array.  Not only is this double what it should be, it is the same for both arrays even though the directivity of the tapered array is obviously less.

So, how does one properly adjust the beam patterns, unnormalized, such that they can be plotted together and reflect the proper directivity?  One solution is to take the normalized beam pattern (where the maximum value is unity), and simply add the directivity index.  Is this the correct method?